# How to support to play audio file in the background

Tags: audio

There is a function in my project to support playing a new audio file even in the background status.I use the MPMoviePlayerController class to play audio files.
  But I found it was started in the active status，then it would continue playing the same audio(if the audio file wasn't finished) in the background status；But it won't start a new audio in the background status.

How can I to support playing a new audio in the backgound status？
    I found the music player of the iphone can support playing a new audio in the background status，when set runloop or random PlayMode.

The following is my code to prove the appearance in fact:

```
(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

   if (pCotnroller1) {
       [pCotnroller1 release];
   }
   pCotnroller1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://r.yhiker.com:9001/0086/32/05/060009/Data/6/00863205060009006_24Kbps.mp3"]];
   pCotnroller1.shouldAutoplay = YES;
   [pCotnroller1 play];
   //it wasn't played here
}


(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
   if (pCotnroller1) {
       switch (pCotnroller1.playbackState) {
          case MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped:
            NSLog(@"播放地址");
            break;

          case MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused:
            NSLog(@"播放暂停");
            break;

          case MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted:
            NSLog(@"播放中断");
            break;

          case MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward:
            break;

          case MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward:
            break;

          default:
            break;
     }

     if (pCotnroller1.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
          //it will come here,and play autoed here

         // [pCotnroller1 play];
     }
     else
     {

     }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried some ways which was found in the net，but it didn't work.Some one had used this way to solute his question.I didn’t know why.

the following is my code：

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [application beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self updateUserLocation]; 
} 

- (void)updateUserLocation
{
    if (!pCotnroller1) {
    //        pCotnroller1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://r.yhiker.com:9001/0086/32/05/PP0041/Data/13/00863205PP0041013_24Kbps.mp3"]];

        NSString *audioDiskPath = [HelpTools returnSpotAudioDiskPath:@"00863205PP0041013"];
          pCotnroller1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioDiskPath/*@"/var/mobile/Applications/E7A06CB2-0856-407D-ABA1-2A846B65CD9D/Library/Caches/Data/0086/32/05/PP0041/Data/13/00863205060005016_24Kbps.mp3"*/]];

        pCotnroller1.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
            [pCotnroller1 play];
            NSLog(@"进入后台");
            UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
            UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskID = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
            if (bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
                [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                NSLog(@"允许后台播放");
            }

            bgTask = taskID;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"飞后台进行播放");
            [pCotnroller1 play];
        }
    }
}
```

the console print:
2013-03-18 16:20:11.844 Sz[1665:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2013-03-18 16:20:11.845 Sz[1665:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2013-03-18 16:20:13.489 Sz[1665:907] 文件存在
2013-03-18 16:20:18.017 Sz[1665:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2013-03-18 16:20:18.998 Sz[1665:907] 进入后台
2013-03-18 16:20:21.269 Sz[1665:907] 播放地址
2013-03-18 16:20:26.251 Sz[1665:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-03-18 16:20:26.307 Sz[1665:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Likely to keep up or full buffer: 0
2013-03-18 16:20:26.309 Sz[1665:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.
2013-03-18 16:20:26.319 Sz[1665:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-03-18 16:20:26.338 Sz[1665:907] [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0